How to choose the best fitting method?
I want to fit non-negative parameters  (xs in the code) to a function fp, given by

where v and L are fixed, given parameters. Computing fp can be done relatively quickly by vectorizing it and using some uniform filtering. The following code implements this optimization problem, where the function cfit (through fitf) slowly adjusts the values of xs by calculating fp at each step and comparing it to the real data  (list in the code), according to

Question: Is there a way of improving this fitting method for this specific function, and the way I am computing it? I tried playing around with scipy.optimize, but everything seems slower than this simple multiplicative gradient method.
Here is the code implementation, where the mean-square error is tracked
import numpy as np
import math

def fitfunction(list, maxiter, error_threshold):
    
    v = 1.4
    st = 5
    exp_v = np.exp(-1/v)
    x00 = np.array([(math.pi/(4*v))*i**(-2) for i in list])
    lm = 1000
    
    def mse(y_true, y_pred):
        mse_value = sum((yt - yp) ** 2 for yt, yp in zip(y_true, y_pred)) / len(y_true)
        return mse_value
    
    def fast_roll_add(dst, src, shift):
        dst[shift:] += src[:-shift]
        dst[:shift] += src[-shift:]
    
    # Main function
    def fp(x, L, v):
        n = len(x)
        y = np.zeros(n)
        last_exp_2_raw = np.zeros(n)
        last_exp_2 = np.ones(n)
        unitary = x.copy()
        for k in range(L+1):
            if k != 0:
                fast_roll_add(unitary, x, k)
                fast_roll_add(unitary, x, -k)
            exp_1_raw = last_exp_2_raw
            exp_1 = last_exp_2
            exp_2_raw = exp_1_raw + unitary / v
            exp_2 = np.exp(-exp_2_raw)
            y += (exp_1 - exp_2) / unitary
            last_exp_2_raw = exp_2_raw
            last_exp_2 = exp_2
        return y

    # Fitting functions
    def fitf(time, lst, x0, j):
        return x0[j] * (lst[j] / time[j])**2
    def cfit(time, lst, x0):
        result = np.empty_like(x0)
        for j in range(len(x0)):
            if fitf(time, lst, x0, j) < 10**(-20):
                result[j] = 10**(-20)
            elif abs(time[j] - lst[j]) < .5:
                result[j] = x0[j]
            else:
                result[j] = fitf(time, lst, x0, j)
        return result
    
    xs = x00
    ys = fp(xs, len(xs)//st, v)
    err = 10**10
    
    for j in range(maxiter):
        if err > error_threshold:
            xs = cfit(list, ys, xs) # Fitting
            ys = fp(xs, len(xs)//st, v) # Update function values
            err = mse(list[lm:-lm], ys[lm:-lm])
            print(str(j+1) + '/' + str(maxiter) + ' err: ' + str('{:.20f}'.format(err)), end="\r")            
        else:
            break

    fire_rates = ['{:.20f}'.format(i) for i in xs]
    time_sim = ys
    
    return [fire_rates, time_sim]

The efficiency of this method is highly data-dependent, so below is a working example with generated data, illustrating how fitting around local maxima seems suboptimal with my method
Minimal working example:
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter1d

# Data generation
np.random.seed(18)
data = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=10, size=10000).cumsum()
data = (data - data.min()) / (data.max() - data.min()) * 500

# Gaussian smoothing
data = gaussian_filter1d(data, sigma=50)

data_fit = fitfunction(data, 100, 2)

and to visualize it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(data, label='Data')
plt.plot(data_fit[1], label='Data Fit')
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('Data and Data Fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


Brief comments:

My multiplicative method seems to be suboptimal around local maxima, as exemplified in the plot above. However, I want to guarantee the best possible fit.
In particular, when using a really large iteration number, the fitting algorithm does not converge at all. This can be seen from around 200 iteration steps, where local values diverge away from the real data value around local maxima.
The implementation of fp is periodic in nature, which leads to massive errors in the ends. Hence, the error err is calculated excluding these regions.
The fitting function provides an even faster fit

def fitf(time, lst, x0, j):
    return x0[j]**(np.log(time[j]) / np.log(lst[j]))

However, when the values come too close to the real value (high iteration number), it is highly unstable, like the multiplicative method.

While this question is not off-topic for Stack Overflow, you might get better answers by cross posting to Computational Science since this kind of thing is more in their wheelhouse

It is a bit difficult to map math and your code. Could you be more specific on what are list_j and list_j(k).

@CoryKramer how can I cross post it? That is a good idea. If not possible, I will probably keep this question up here, as user2285236 was kind enough to start a bounty on it.

@jlandercy I have edited that section to make it clear. Essentially, I have data (list) on the true values of fp that I want to fit, through the relation given by the first equation. Let me know if this is more clear now. The fitting method seems to generally converge, but I want to improve its efficiency somehow, as I will need to fit a large data set. An analytical inversion is being discussed here, though a numerical approach would me more than enough for me.

Do you have a scientific reference that we can read, to get more details. As it is formulated now it looks like recursive problem with circular reference to your function fp. That could explain why you can solve it by specific iteration with dedicated code but struggle to optimize it with scipy. I am not saying it unfeasible, but for sure that will be an interesting challenge. If you have a scientific reference please add it.

@jlandercy Unfortunately I don't, I came up with the fitting formula myself, and an extension involves x0[j]**(np.log(time[j]) / np.log(lst[j])), as mentioned. This is faster, but ultimately becomes unstable. I suspect the fitting step could potentially involve some type of local averaging of sorts, but the analytical inversion is itself hard. Ultimately, the main expression for fp is, in a sense, a differential operator involving convolutions, so I wonder whether there is any optimization framework for convolution-based objective functions.

What is the objective of your optimization? You want to find the best v and L, which fits the data best?

Can you please edit your formula to replace the elided |i| <= k with explicit start and end indices on every sigma?

@Reinderien Done, hope it is more clear now.

@VardanGrigoryants v and L are fixed constant. I want to find the values of the list xs that best fit fp.

More generally, I have edited the example dataset to show an example where my fitting approach is suboptimal, which seems to be around local maxima, as exemplified in the plot. This is what I want to fix! In particular, when using a really large iteration number, the fitting algorithm does not converge at all.

So, number of learnable parameters is variable, not fixed, right, i.e. the length of list xs can be arbitrary number?

@VardanGrigoryants length of xs is fixed (1 <= j <= n), for some n, and is the same as the length of the data.

Generally, don't cross-post. If you asked on the other site too, probably delete it before you get diverging answers on different sites.

Apparent cross-site duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4934778/a-hard-optimization-problem

@tripleee Not quite. There I am asking for an analytical inversion, if attainable. Here, I am asking for a numerical-fitting approach, which seems more realistic. Answers will by nature be diverging because the questions are different, though I agree answering the analytical (harder) problem would make this question relatively pointless. Thanks for pointing it out nonetheless.

This answer achieves only moderate speed gains (10%).
However, I have removed unnecessary loops and array copies. I have also renamed a few variables if they had different names in other parts of the code (but were otherwise identical), and removed others that were superfluous or even unused. As a result, the code is much shorter and a bit more readable.
I hope that it aids others in finding more substantial improvements.
import numpy as np

def fitfunction(data, maxiter, error_threshold, v=1.4, maximum_shift=2_000):

    def mse(y_true, y_pred, margin=1000):
        if margin > 0:
            return np.sum((y_true[margin:-margin] -
                           y_pred[margin:-margin])**2)
        else:
            return np.sum((y_true - y_pred)**2)

    def fast_roll_add(dst, src, shift):
        dst[shift:] += src[:-shift]
        dst[:shift] += src[-shift:]

    # Main function
    def fp(x, maximum_shift, v):
        unitary = x.copy()
        exponents = unitary / v
        new_powers = np.exp(-exponents)
        y = (1 - new_powers) / unitary
        for k in range(1, maximum_shift+1):
            fast_roll_add(unitary, x, k)
            fast_roll_add(unitary, x, -k)
            exponents += unitary / v
            old_powers = new_powers
            new_powers = np.exp(-exponents)
            y += (old_powers - new_powers) / unitary
        return y

    # Fitting function
    # This is the literal rewrite.
    # def cfit(y_true, y_pred, x):
    #     x_new = x * (y_pred / y_true)**2
    #     residuals = np.abs(y_true - y_pred)
    #     return np.where(residuals < .5, x, np.clip(x_new, 1e-20, None))
    # However, checking the residuals seems to be unnecessary.
    def cfit(y_true, y_pred, x):
        return np.clip(x * (y_pred / y_true)**2, 1e-20, None)

    err = np.zeros(maxiter)

    x = np.pi / (4 * v * data**2)
    y = fp(x, maximum_shift, v)
    err[0] = mse(data, y)
    print("1" + '/' + str(maxiter) + ' err: ' + str('{:.2f}'.format(err[0])), end="\r")

    for j in range(1, maxiter):
        if err[j-1] > error_threshold:
            x = cfit(data, y, x) # Fitting
            y = fp(x, maximum_shift, v) # Update function values
            err[j] = mse(data, y)
            print(str(j+1) + '/' + str(maxiter) + ' err: ' + str('{:.2f}'.format(err[j])), end="\r")
        else:
            break
    print()

    return x, y, err


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import time
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset

    from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter1d

    # Data generation
    np.random.seed(18)
    data = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=10, size=10_000).cumsum()
    data = (data - data.min()) / (data.max() - data.min()) * 500

    # Gaussian smoothing
    data = gaussian_filter1d(data, sigma=50)

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
    fig.canvas.draw()
    ax1_inset = ax1.inset_axes([0.55, 0.05, 0.4, 0.4])

    for v in [1.4, 0.05]:
        tic = time.time()
        x, y, err = fitfunction(data, 10, 0.1, v=v)
        toc = time.time()
        print(f"Time elapsed: {toc-tic:.2f} seconds")
        ax1.plot(y, label=f"v = {v:.2f}")
        ax1_inset.plot(y, label=f"v = {v:.2f}")
        ax2.plot(err, label=f"v = {v:.2f}")

    ax1.plot(data, linestyle=':', color="black", label="Original data")
    ax1_inset.plot(data, linestyle=':', color="black", label="Original data")

    ax1_inset.set_xlim(7_300, 8_000)
    ax1_inset.set_ylim(330, 410)
    ax1_inset.set_xticks([])
    ax1_inset.set_yticks([])
    mark_inset(ax1, ax1_inset, loc1=2, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="0.5")

    ax1.set_title("Data & fits")
    ax1.set_xlabel("Time")
    ax2.set_ylabel("Value")
    ax1.legend(loc="upper left")

    ax2.set_title("Loss improvement")
    ax2.set_xlabel("Iteration")
    ax2.set_ylabel("MSE")
    ax2.legend(loc="upper right")

    plt.show()


Edit
I think it is worth noting that there is a lot of room for improvement in the parameterization of your optimization. For example, your choice of v, which is effectively the inverse of your learning rate, is far too conservative. With v=0.05, the fit converges within 3 iterations, even if the error threshold is reduced to 0.1.


I have tried it, but on a Jupyter notebook this actually seems to run slower.

One of the issues I am having is guaranteeing convergence around local maxima, where the algorithm oscillates quite a bit. This becomes more evident by changing sigma to 50, in the data generation example. See the updated post.

Reduce your v parameter. See my edits.

v can't be reduced, sorry. That is an important factor in my model, and that value is fixed. Lowering v makes convergence much easier (for this data set at least), but that is not the problem I am trying to solve.

Having said that, I do believe v plays a big part in determining fitting limitations, especially around local maxima, but I want to achieve the best possible fit under that fixed value of 1.4.

You do you, but there is no mystery then why you can't converge on a better solution more quickly. You are making giant leaps back and forth, back and forth, around the local minima, instead of making small but consistent progress towards the minima. No fancy python tricks will be able to change that.

I appreciate your perspective, but I want to clarify that my goal isn't to seek 'fancy Python tricks.' Rather, I am in pursuit of a more insightful set of criteria for convergence that ensures both efficiency and accuracy in reaching the solution. In a way, we are looking at some type of discrete differential operator involving convolutions, so I believe something more could be said about it. What exactly, I am not sure. Maybe something involving a moving average. My solution is far from optimal, so I'm open to any suggestions that might help refine our approach to this problem.

Some variant of a search direction method possibly with a weighting that emphasises the peaks and a penalty function that discourages it from going too far combined with conjugate gradients ought to be able to handle it. You may need to do something about the boundary conditions too since inherent misfit there may be making life difficult for your optimiser as well. Allowing v to evolve from the values with an easy to fit  to where you actually want it might also help speed things up.

I'd recommend to compute the error of the prediction and compensate it directly into xs with some learning rate. The idea to have more granular control over xs. It is probably something similar to Straight-Through Estimators, in terms of the error is directly back propagated to the variable. So, your fitting functions will be as follows:
    # # Fitting functions
    def fitf(time, lst, x0, j):
        learning_rate = 1e-8
        return x0[j] + learning_rate*(lst[j] - time[j])
        
    def cfit(time, lst, x0):
        result = np.empty_like(x0)
        for j in range(len(x0)):
            result[j] = fitf(time, lst, x0, j)
        return result

Please note, you will need to choose correct learning_rate for different data. This will be your hyper parameter. Very small changes in learning rate may cause divergence. Since, the initial xs has the order of 1e-06, I have chosen 1e-8 learning rate, and it worked. But, you will need to increase the number of iterations to be around 400, i.e. maxiter=400, or even higher, because of small learning rate.
You will get the following result:

With max_iter=1000, the result is even better (note the difference on the left side of the figures):

The full code:
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter1d

def fitfunction(list, maxiter, error_threshold):
    
    v = 1.4
    st = 5
    exp_v = np.exp(-1/v)
    x00 = np.array([(math.pi/(4*v))*i**(-2) for i in list])
    lm = 1000
    
    def mse(y_true, y_pred):
        mse_value = sum((yt - yp) ** 2 for yt, yp in zip(y_true, y_pred)) / len(y_true)
        return mse_value
    
    def fast_roll_add(dst, src, shift):
        dst[shift:] += src[:-shift]
        dst[:shift] += src[-shift:]
    
    # Main function
    def fp(x, L, v):
        n = len(x)
        y = np.zeros(n)
        last_exp_2_raw = np.zeros(n)
        last_exp_2 = np.ones(n)
        unitary = x.copy()
        for k in range(L+1):
            if k != 0:
                fast_roll_add(unitary, x, k)
                fast_roll_add(unitary, x, -k)
            exp_1_raw = last_exp_2_raw
            exp_1 = last_exp_2
            exp_2_raw = exp_1_raw + unitary / v
            exp_2 = np.exp(-exp_2_raw)
            y += (exp_1 - exp_2) / unitary
            last_exp_2_raw = exp_2_raw
            last_exp_2 = exp_2
        return y

    # # Fitting functions
    def fitf(time, lst, x0, j):
        learning_rate = 1e-8
        return x0[j] + learning_rate*(lst[j] - time[j])
        
    def cfit(time, lst, x0):
        result = np.empty_like(x0)
        for j in range(len(x0)):
            result[j] = fitf(time, lst, x0, j)
        return result
 
    xs = x00
    ys = fp(xs, len(xs)//st, v)
    err = 10**10
    
    for j in range(maxiter):
        if err > error_threshold:
            xs = cfit(list, ys, xs) # Fitting
            ys = fp(xs, len(xs)//st, v) # Update function values
            err = mse(list[lm:-lm], ys[lm:-lm])
            print(str(j+1) + '/' + str(maxiter) + ' err: ' + str('{:.20f}'.format(err)), end="\r")            
        else:
            break

    fire_rates = ['{:.20f}'.format(i) for i in xs]
    time_sim = ys
    
    return [fire_rates, time_sim]


# Data generation
np.random.seed(18)
data = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=10, size=10000).cumsum()
data = (data - data.min()) / (data.max() - data.min()) * 500

# Gaussian smoothing
data = gaussian_filter1d(data, sigma=50)

data_fit = fitfunction(data, 500, 0.2)


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(data, label='Data')
plt.plot(data_fit[1], label='Data Fit')
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('Data and Data Fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

And here is the modified code provided by Paul Brodersen:
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter1d

def fitfunction(data, maxiter, error_threshold, v=1.4, maximum_shift=2_000):

    def mse(y_true, y_pred, margin=1000):
        if margin > 0:
            return np.sum((y_true[margin:-margin] -
                           y_pred[margin:-margin])**2)
        else:
            return np.sum((y_true - y_pred)**2)

    def fast_roll_add(dst, src, shift):
        dst[shift:] += src[:-shift]
        dst[:shift] += src[-shift:]

    # Main function
    def fp(x, maximum_shift, v):
        unitary = x.copy()
        exponents = unitary / v
        new_powers = np.exp(-exponents)
        y = (1 - new_powers) / unitary
        for k in range(1, maximum_shift+1):
            fast_roll_add(unitary, x, k)
            fast_roll_add(unitary, x, -k)
            exponents += unitary / v
            old_powers = new_powers
            new_powers = np.exp(-exponents)
            y += (old_powers - new_powers) / unitary
        return y

    # Fitting function
    # This is the literal rewrite.
    # def cfit(y_true, y_pred, x):
    #     x_new = x * (y_pred / y_true)**2
    #     residuals = np.abs(y_true - y_pred)
    #     return np.where(residuals < .5, x, np.clip(x_new, 1e-20, None))
    # However, checking the residuals seems to be unnecessary.
    def cfit(y_true, y_pred, x):
    
        return x + 1e-8*(y_pred-y_true)

    err = np.zeros(maxiter)

    x = np.pi / (4 * v * data**2)
    y = fp(x, maximum_shift, v)
    err[0] = mse(data, y)
    print("1" + '/' + str(maxiter) + ' err: ' + str('{:.2f}'.format(err[0])), end="\r")

    for j in range(1, maxiter):
        if err[j-1] > error_threshold:
            x = cfit(data, y, x) # Fitting
            y = fp(x, maximum_shift, v) # Update function values
            err[j] = mse(data, y)
            print(str(j+1) + '/' + str(maxiter) + ' err: ' + str('{:.2f}'.format(err[j])), end="\r")
        else:
            break
    print()

    return x, y, err

# Data generation
np.random.seed(18)
data = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=10, size=10_000).cumsum()
data = (data - data.min()) / (data.max() - data.min()) * 500

# Gaussian smoothing
data = gaussian_filter1d(data, sigma=50)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
fig.canvas.draw()
ax1_inset = ax1.inset_axes([0.55, 0.05, 0.4, 0.4])

v=1.4
tic = time.time()
x, y, err = fitfunction(data, 400, 0.1, v=v)
toc = time.time()
print(f"Time elapsed: {toc-tic:.2f} seconds")
ax1.plot(y, label=f"v = {v:.2f}")
ax1_inset.plot(y, label=f"v = {v:.2f}")
ax2.plot(err, label=f"v = {v:.2f}")

ax1.plot(data, linestyle=':', color="black", label="Original data")
ax1_inset.plot(data, linestyle=':', color="black", label="Original data")

ax1_inset.set_xlim(7_300, 8_000)
ax1_inset.set_ylim(330, 410)
ax1_inset.set_xticks([])
ax1_inset.set_yticks([])
mark_inset(ax1, ax1_inset, loc1=2, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="0.5")

ax1.set_title("Data & fits")
ax1.set_xlabel("Time")
ax2.set_ylabel("Value")
ax1.legend(loc="upper left")

ax2.set_title("Loss improvement")
ax2.set_xlabel("Iteration")
ax2.set_ylabel("MSE")
ax2.legend(loc="upper right")

plt.show()

This will have the following result:

Edit:
For non-negative combined solution discussed in the comments, you can try the following:
    # Fitting functions
    def fitf(time, lst, x0, j):
        x_new = x0[j] + 1e-8*(lst[j] - time[j])
        if x_new < 0:
            return x0[j] * (lst[j] / time[j])**2
        return x_new
        
    def cfit(time, lst, x0):
        result = np.empty_like(x0)
        for j in range(len(x0)):
            if fitf(time, lst, x0, j) < 1e-20:
                result[j] = 1e-20
            elif abs(time[j] - lst[j]) < .5:
                result[j] = x0[j]
            else:
                result[j] = fitf(time, lst, x0, j)
        return result

The idea is to use multiplicative approach whenever the item of xs will be negative during the update of my approach. Please, note here you need to use may be around 100 iterations for the best solution. Otherwise, please implement early stopping, i.e. whenever the error starts to increase break the loop. Per me the result is worse than each separate approach, but you can try to adjust. Hope, you will find some better insights.
For non-negative solution you can also try to compensate the negative values with positive ones, i.e. the sum of xs during the training should remain constant. Here, I'm checking if there is any negative value in xs, if so I'm trying to add that negative value to the closest positive value, which sum still positive. Probably I haven't done this optimal, for 200 iterations it will take around 20 mins or so.
    def cfit(y_true, y_pred, x):

        x_vals = x + 1e-8*(y_pred-y_true)
        negative_indicies = np.where(x_vals<0)[0]
        positive_indicies = np.where(x_vals>0)[0]
        if len(negative_indicies)>0:
            neg_i = []
            pos_j = []
            for i, n in enumerate(x_vals[negative_indicies]):
                for j, p in enumerate(x_vals[positive_indicies]):
                    if p+n>1e-10:
                        neg_i.append(i)
                        pos_j.append(j)
            
        
            x_vals[positive_indicies[pos_j]] = x_vals[positive_indicies[pos_j]] + x_vals[negative_indicies[neg_i]]
            x_vals[negative_indicies[neg_i]] = 1e-10            
    
        return x_vals

The result will have slightly improvement with the cost of long training:


This looks promising, however I should have mentioned that the values in xs should be non-negative (which I necessarily get with my method). Your learning_rate eventually leads to negative values of xs (check data_fit[0] at the end, for example). I should have been clear from the beginning, but I have now edited the question to make this explicit. Do you think your method could still work with this condition?

Then, may be this is the reason you are getting suboptimal solution. I mean may be there is no non-negative solution for this problem you want? Whatsoever for non-negative solution you can try to combine your multiplicative approach with mine or try to compensate the negative values within neighourbuding points, i.e. make the negative value to be 0, but add that value to the closest positive value, but not far from it by 10, during the training.

Yes! I believe that is indeed the point, there is no exact solution, but I want the best possible fit with non-negative xs. The issue I have with my approach is that at some point, the algorithm gets unstable, as I am dealing with very small values in xs, as fp moves closer to local maxima. I agree, I think a combination could be ideal, but it's not clear how to do it.

I've added the combined approach. The idea is to use multiplicative approach for negative values. But, seems the result isn't better than each of the separate approach.

Another insight would be the following: please note that you get the suboptimal solution on local maximas, but not the minimas. Try to find why is that, since both are extremums, what is unique with maximas making it worse compared to minimas. For experiment you can fit the inverse of data, like this: data_fit = fitfunction( data.max()-data+data.min(), 100, 2), and plot like this plt.plot(data.max()+data.min() - data_fit[1], label='Data Fit')

Thank you! Just out of curiosity, would computing the gradient of fp in terms of xs help if I use scipy.optimize? Can I still enforce non-negative parameters there and work with constraints? Just thinking in terms of looking for a gradient descent method. See here and here, for example.

I think yes, you can. You can try bounds and constraints arguments for scipy.optimize.minimize function.
